# Image Cropper not crop as square image

Tags: jquery, html, image, crop, jcrop

Iam using Image Cropper ( [here official site](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) ), and my crop result not in square image. as image below :

**CROP SELECTION**

### [image: crop selection]

**CROP RESULT**

[image: crop result]

this is my html :

```
<input type="hidden" name="dataX" id="dataX">
<input type="hidden" name="dataY" id="dataY">
<input type="hidden" name="dataHeight" id="dataHeight">
<input type="hidden" name="dataWidth" id="dataWidth">
```

and my jquery :

```
var $image = $(".dynamic-image img"),
    $dataX = $("#dataX"),
    $dataY = $("#dataY"),
    $dataHeight = $("#dataHeight"),
    $dataWidth = $("#dataWidth");

$image.cropper({
  aspectRatio: 1,
  minContainerWidth:760,
  minContainerHeight:350,
  done: function(data) {
    $dataX.val(data.x);
    $dataY.val(data.y);
    $dataHeight.val(data.height);
    $dataWidth.val(data.width);
  }
});
```

*sory for my english :)

Comment: Is the image ratio being changed in the browser? E.g. To fit the surrounding container.

Comment: no changed in the browser :(

Comment: I used JCrop and worked perfectly.

Comment: JCrop error inside modal bootstrap 3..

Comment: What error do you have

Comment: i am sorry, problem solved.
my problem inside codeigniter image lbrary :)

i am glad with your help :)